# $P(X>4-Y)=P(Y>4-X)$, but I get different results...

Tags: calculus, probability

X, Y are r.v., with joint density $f(x,y)=1/50(x^2+y^2)$ for $0<x<2, \ 1<y<4$.

I want to calculate P(X+Y>4).

$P(X>4-Y)= \int^4_1 \int^2_{4-y} 1/50(x^2+y^2) \ dx \ dy=23/50$ (confirmed in Mathematica).
However, when computing $P(Y>4-X)=\int^2_0 \int^4_{4-x} 1/50(x^2+y^2) \ dy \ dx=8/15$ (confirmed in Mathematica)

However, I should have obtained the same value, no?

Comment: Bounds of integration in the first integral are incorrect. It should be $\int_2^4\,dy$

Comment: Let's look at the first integral. What happens when $4-y>2$? What's the density in your case and what it ought to be?

Comment: Much Obliged  @A.S.

Comment: Much Obliged @Ennar

Comment: You are welcome. It's helpful not to write the boundaries immediately, but start off with appropriate indicator functions.

Comment: @Ennar How would you work with the indicator functions in this case?

Comment: Something like $\iint f(x,y) \mathbf 1_{\langle 0,2\rangle}(x)\mathbf 1_{\langle 1,4\rangle}(y)\mathbf 1_{\langle 4-y,\infty\rangle}(x)\, dxdy$ and merge it into one condition for $x$ and one for $y$.

Comment: @Ennar Ok. Thanks ;)